# Oracle ORA-30004 when using SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH function,

Tags: oracle

`ORA-30004` when using `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH` function, cannot have seperator as part of the column

> Action: Use another seperator which does not occur in any column
>   value, then retry.

Error on:

```
select ...
Sys_Connect_By_Path(myVariable || ':' || mySecondVariable, ' --> ') "myNewVar",
...
```

Works:

```
select ...
Sys_Connect_By_Path(myVariable || ':' || mySecondVariable, ' -> ') "myNewVar",
...
```

In the data we found some text like this

- `SomeText B--More Text`
- `SomeText A--More Text`

Since there is no `'-->'` or for that mater no '`-->`' in the data why does the first one error? The second one has a space in front and on the end.

Comment: Is it the blank before and after the --> ?

Comment: yes - the previous programmer I think was trying to add a space-->space

Comment: Is there a typo and you meant `SomeText B-->More Text` rather than `SomeText B--More Text`? Because then it is clear: blank before and after is not equal.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thats because `--` is a part of `-->` separator but not a part of `->` separator.

Even if your data value has `-->` this query should not error. Like below.

```
SQL> select Sys_Connect_By_Path('SomeText B-->More Text' || ':' || 'SomeText A-->More Text', ' --> ') "myNewVar"
from dual
connect by  rownum<=3;

myNewVar                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
----------------------------------------------------
--> SomeText B-->More Text:SomeText A-->More Text                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
--> SomeText B-->More Text:SomeText A-->More Text --> SomeText B-->More Text:SomeText A-->More Text                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
--> SomeText B-->More Text:SomeText A-->More Text --> SomeText B-->More Text:SomeText A-->More Text --> SomeText B-->More Text:SomeText A-->More Text
```

The separator above is `-->`, notice the whitespace. This whitespace is considered as part of the separator i.e. `chr(1)||chr(45)||chr(45)||chr(62)||chr(1)`. This entire string is not a part of your data or column value.

Where as below would error

```
SQL> select Sys_Connect_By_Path('SomeText B-->More Text' || ':' || 'SomeText A-->More Text', '-->') "myNewVar"
from dual
connect by  rownum<=3;

ORA-30004: when using SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH function, cannot have seperator as part of column value
30004. 00000 -  "when using SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH function, cannot have seperator as part of column value"
*Cause:    
*Action:   Use another seperator which does not occur in any column value,
           then retry.
```

The separator above is `-->`, notice there is no whitespace i.e. `chr(45)||chr(45)||chr(62)`. This entire string is indeed a part of your data or column value and hence the error.

And here's a solution (performance un-tested)

```
select regexp_replace(Sys_Connect_By_Path('SomeText B-->More Text' || ':' || 'SomeText A-->More Text', ' -> '),' -> ','-->') "myNewVar"
from dual
connect by  rownum<=3;

myNewVar                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
--------------------------------------
-->SomeText B-->More Text:SomeText A-->More Text                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
-->SomeText B-->More Text:SomeText A-->More Text-->SomeText B-->More Text:SomeText A-->More Text                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
-->SomeText B-->More Text:SomeText A-->More Text-->SomeText B-->More Text:SomeText A-->More Text-->SomeText B-->More Text:SomeText A-->More Text
```

**Explanation -** Here(in the query above) `->` (with space) is not part of the data here i.e. `-->`. Once the column is conected by path the `regexp_replace` replaces all occurences of `->` with `-->` so this way you still get to have `-->` as your separator instead of `->`.

Comment: I hear you but it does error when I have the -- and when I change it form --> to -> it work.

Comment: Thats because `--` is a part of `-->` but not a part of `->`

Comment: The error says `when using SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH function, cannot have seperator as part of column value` your separator `-->` has `--` on it which is a part of the column value, where `->` is not a part of column value.

Comment: However the data has a - in it why doesn't that error like the one before?

Comment: I rectified that. See the modified answer

Comment: But still I do not understand. I tested around and when I have strings with `--` in it but the separater is `-->` I do still not get an error. I assert that some column of `myVariable` or `mySecondVariable` must have a `-->` in it.

Comment: @hol The results you are getting is correct. Strings with `--` will not error with separator `-->`. The OP did not say what `myVariable` or `mySecondVariable` contains, but assuming they only contain `--`, the queries he mentioned shouldn't fail.