# Troubleshooting for Oracle ORA-30004

Tags: sql, oracle

As titled,

Normally how would one troubleshoot for this error? Do i need to know which table this error came from?

And is there any way or query that i can use to check the separator used that causes ORA-30004 error on that errored table?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870605/oracle-ora-30004-when-using-sys-connect-by-path-function

Comment: I checked on that one before i asked. I see that the guy knew the source of the problem before asking and only wanted a clarification of it. My question was more to those who knew that the error was ORA-30004 but didn't know what was the root cause of it. So i'm kind of lost here as to how to begin the troubleshooting for this sort of Oracle error.